# Find out Card height to modify

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make change to this template [startbootstr app](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/business-frontpage/). For this original code:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Find Out More!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Find Out More!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Find Out More!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I removed divs with class="card-footer" to get rid of "Find our more" buttons. This however, creates a "huge" blank space below "card-text". Using browser's style inspector, I couldn't locate which css class is responsible for the card's height. I do see "h-100" is applied to the Div, but making change to it doesn't change overall height. From where the height of above sample code/Card is controlled?   TIA

Comment: I also removed card footer and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fixman993/d34sjec6/1/)
This is your example without `class="card-footer"`.

I think you have a problem with your CSS